# Taking input of two different data type in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Hey How can I take two kinds of data input from a single line in Ruby. Generally I use

```
X, Y = gets.split.map(&:to_i)
```

For taking two integer number from the same line. Now what can I do for taking integer and decimal number input from the same line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's most clear to do it in three steps in the obvious way: `x_str, y_str = gets.split.map(&:strip); x = x_str.to_i; y = y_str.to_f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is to replace `to_i` with `to_f` (to_float). This will cope with floats, but will convert *all* your inputs to float, even if an int would do.

You have some other difficulties with your code:

- `X` and`Y` are constants, because they start with capital letters. This will cause difficulties if you ever want to reassign them.
- It expects 2 inputs – no more or no less. A 3rd input will be ignored. If you only have one input, `Y` will be `nil`.

To take different types of input, you'll have to parse it intelligently. Here I'm using [regular expressions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Regexp.html) for the parsing. You could take other approaches, eg test if `arg.to_i == arg.to_f` (`false` if it's a float, `true` if it's an int...or if it's neither float nor int).

```
def parse_input(args)
    args.map do |arg|
        case arg
            when /^-?[\d]+$/
                arg.to_i
            when /^-?[\d]+\.?[\d]+$/
                arg.to_f
            else
                arg
        end
    end
end

input = parse_input(gets.split)
input.each { |i| puts "#{i} (#{i.class})"}
```

You can take that `input` array and pass it round other functions, without it having to tontain exactly 2 members.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
types = [:to_i, :to_f]
x, y = gets.split.zip(types).map {|i| i[0].send i[1]}
```

Comment: You don't need `zip`: `x, y = gets.split.map { |s| s.public_send(types.shift) }`. I can't say I'm fond of either solution, however, as they unnecessarily complicate and obscure what is a very simple operation.